# Свич для умного дома

Tags: умный-дом

Хочу сделать умный дом на Home Assistant. На данный момент дом строится, планирую сделать только умные выключатели, без сервера(потом как нибудь добавлю), схема: реле + выключатель. Купил и протестировал RF [радиореле](https://aliexpress.ru/item/1005005439466535.html?sku_id=12000033087660391&spm=a2g2w.productlist.search_results.2.5d944db4sXdtiM) на 1 канал, все круто. Но не хочу реле в каждом подрозетнике или много на дин рейке, и не хочу что бы они все присасывались по Wi-fi. Вопрос: есть какое-то устройство на, грубо говоря, 15-20 каналов(линий света) которое может принимать как RF сигнал от RF выключателей, так и получать сигнал по Wi-fi от сервера на Home Assistant?

Comment: В подрозетник пихать реле - отстой. Не особо удобно. Лучше на лампу вешать его. Под натяжным места больше) две выключателя+фаза+ноль и в подрозетник и на потолок.

Answer (score 0):

По теме вопроса Sonoff RF Bridge например можно поставить или самодельную  на базе https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/rflink/